# Getting bean from appContext using ApplicationContextAware interface

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have a bean implementing **ApplicationContextAware** interface, it is registered in my **.xml** config, along with **context:annotation-config** and component scan. But when i get a bean from the context, bean's dependencies (injected with **@Autowire**) appears null.

When i use context obtained from **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext**, everything works fine (using same config).

Do i need to change my configuration in order to get context obtained with ApplicationContextAware bean 'working'?

Comment: when you autowire that same bean, are the dependencies not null?

Comment: how do you create applicationcontext in first case?

Comment: No, you generally don't need to do that. Probably is a misconfiguration in your .xml file. Posting an excerpt of it or how you obtain the ApplicationContext would allow us to help you further.

Comment: @Adrijardi : what do You mean? I have a bean A, implementing ApplicationContextAware, in which i obtain appContext, then im invoking appContext.getBean(bean B), and all dependencies in B are null.

I do not create it, it;s set by setApplicationContext method in ApplicationContextAware interface. Part of my xml config:

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z" />

<bean class="x.y.z.A" /> <-- bean implementing ApplicationContextAware

<bean id="xxx" class="x.y.z.B" /> <-- bean with null dependencies after getting it from appContext in bean A.